# React Hook Form does not passing the data

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am trying to validate a form using 'react-hook-form' the issue is that all the form data is undefined.
This is the form component:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <FormGroup className="mb-3">
                  <FormText>Full Name</FormText>
                  <Input
                    id="fullName"
                    className="input-transparent pl-3"
                    type="text"
                    style={{ border: inputError ? "1px solid red" : "" }}
                    name="fullName"
                    placeholder="Henry"
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, setFormData)}
                    {...register("fullName", { name: "fullName" })}
                    defaultValue={fullName}
                  />
                  {errors.fullName  && <small>This field is required</small>}
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup className="my-3">
                  <FormText>Email</FormText>
                  <Input
                    id="email"
                    className="input-transparent pl-3"
                    type="text"
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="henrymonk@mail.com"
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, setFormData)}
                    {...register("email", { name: "email" })}
                    defaultValue={email}
                  />
                  {errors.email && <small>This field is required</small>}
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup className="my-3">
                  <FormText>Phone Number</FormText>
                  <Input
                    id="phone"
                    className="input-transparent pl-3"
                    type="text"
                    name="phone"
                    placeholder="+123456789"
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, setFormData)}
                    {...register("phone", { name: "phone" })}
                    defaultValue={phone}
                  />
                  {errors.phone && <small>This field is required</small>}
                </FormGroup>
                
                <FormGroup className="my-3">
                  <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <FormText></FormText>
                    {/* <Link to="/error">Forgot password?</Link> */}
                  </div>
                  <FileUploader
                    content={`Upload Photo`}
                    icon={`image`}
                    onChange={handleFileSelect}
                  />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup className="my-3">
                  <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <FormText>Password</FormText>
                    <Link to="/error">Forgot password?</Link>
                  </div>
                  <InputGroup>
                    <Input
                      id="password"
                      className="input-transparent pl-3"
                      style={{ borderRight: "none" }}
                      type={showPassword === true ? 'text' : 'password'}
                      name="password"
                      placeholder="Place your password here"
                      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, setFormData)}
                      {...register("password", { name: "password" })}
                      defaultValue={password}
                    />
                    <Button
                      color="white"
                      onClick={handleShowPassword}
                      style={{
                        margin: 0,
                        padding: "0px 20px",
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        alignItems: "center",
                        borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
                        borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
                        borderRight: "1px solid #6b859e65",
                        borderBlock: "1px solid #6b859e65",
                      }}
                    >
                      <i className={showPassword === false ? `eva eva-eye-outline` : `eva eva-eye-off-outline`} />
                    </Button>
                  </InputGroup>
                  {errors.password && <small>This field is required</small>}
                </FormGroup>
                
                <div className="bg-widget d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <Button
                    className="rounded-pill my-3"
                    type="submit"
                    color="secondary-red"
                  >
                    Sign Up
                  </Button>
                </div>
                <p className="dividing-line my-3">&#8195;Or&#8195;</p>
                <div className="d-flex align-items-center my-3">
                  <p className="social-label mb-0">Login with</p>
                  <div className="socials">
                    <a href="https://flatlogic.com/">
                      <GoogleIcon />
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://flatlogic.com/">
                      <GithubIcon />
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <Link to="/login">Enter your Cradev account</Link>
                </div>
                
              </form>
```

As you can see, the form is uncontrolled, From 'react-hook-form' I used useForm() hook where I extracted handleSubmit() and register() functions.

The onSubmit() and handleChange() functions are like this:

```
 const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    try {
      console.log("data", data)
      await dispatch(registerUser(data)).unwrap();
     // props.history.push("/template");
    } catch (error) {
      const errorMessages = error?.errors?.map((err) => err.msg);
      toast.error(errorMessages.join("\n"), {
        theme: "colored",
      });
    }
  };

const handleChange = (event, setValue) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    console.log(formData)
    setValue((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
    
  };
```

and before that I defined the state of form data:

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: '',
    fullName: '',
    password: '',
    phone: '',
  });
```

Can someone explain to me where is the problem ? How to fix it ?
This is what I get on the console:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to set initialValues when initializing `useForm`:

```
const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm({
  defaultValues: { email: '',
    fullName: '',
    password: '',
    phone: '',
}
})
```

there is no need for `useState` to keep the form values.